# Redirecting if a URL contains a particular substring

Tags: apache, redirect

I want to write an apache redirect rule to redirect if the provided url contains a particular substring.  For example, say a user hits the server with the url `http://bloop1.toop.com`.  I want to redirect them to `http://bloop2.toop.com`.  From looking around online, I wrote a rule something like the following:

```
RewwriteRule .+bloop1 http://bloop2.toop.com
```

But that doesn't work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you tried it with `RewriteRule` instead of `RewwriteRule`? Hopefully it's just a typo in your OP and not in your code.

Comment: Yes, I have it defined in the conf file as RewriteRule.  It was just a typo when I posted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also create a DNS CNAME entry to point the bloop1.toop.com subdomain to bloop2.toop.com. This is probably preferable if you are going to see a lot of traffic to that particular subdomain, as it will shift the workload from your webserver to the client's DNS lookup.